# Alternative method for PublishRequest() in new Masstransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, response, masstransit

I'm trying to update my code from old version of Masstransit to newer version (v. 3) of it with RabbitMQ, and I want to use a request/response mode that my old code is:

```
public static void SendCommand<TCommand>(this IServiceBus bus, TCommand command, Action<InlineRequestConfigurator<TCommand>> callback) where TCommand : CommandBase
{
    command.Validate();
    bus.PublishRequest(command, callback); // Here is my problem
}
```

I can't find any alternative method for `PublishRequest()` in `IBusControl` that I think it is defined instead of `IServiceBus`.

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you truly need to publish your request (versus sending it to a specific endpoint)? Requests should typically be sent to a specific endpoint.

This is well described in the documentation:
http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/request_response.html

The fact that your method is called SendCommand makes this resonate pretty well.

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris Patterson.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is on the `IBus` interface as the `IServiceBus` was removed in MT 3. `IBus` is just a collection of interfaces, so you could use the lowest common interface that supports the methods you need.

Comment: I think your answer is not clear!? - Can you please provide some codes that you believe it is helpful for OP?

Comment: var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IResponseCommand>();<br/>
publisher.SendCommand(command, c =>
{
    c.Handle<IResponseCommand>(r =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(r);
    });
    c.HandleTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), timeout =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(new ResponseCommand(command.CorrelationId, AlarmType.Error, "Timeout", false));
    });
});